Document layout error
Since I share my project on overleaf, I have a layout problem with my Tufte_book document, with the following error message:
emmentaler-11.otf[Scale=MatchLowercase]
And the message of overleaf is as follows in front of the line code in the preamble:
\documentclass[a4paper,nobib,twoside,symmetric,justified,marginals=raggedouter]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\newfontfamily\emmentaler{emmentaler-11.otf}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\begin{document}
\end{document}

Undefined control sequence.
LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
Undefined control sequence.
How can I solve this problem ?

This question might be better suited for a fortune teller than for tex.stackexchange.com

you have not shown any onput nor said what the error is just shown a fragment of the context line that gives some context for the location of the error. You need to gove at least some information if you want anyone to answer. Show the full lerror from th log in a code blok (three backticks)  from the ! to the ?

But I would guess you are referencing a font that is not found.

Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a document environment.

The format you are showing is not the format of a tex error message and you have omitted the main part of the message that says which command is undefined.  Also an undefined command is a simple syntax error in your document or package it is not what I would call a "layout error" tex's document layout has not had an error, it has not even started.

have you loaded the fontspec package (and used lualatex) ?  \newfontfamily is not defined by default.

@DavidCarlisle Thank you, I have to change the compiler ! Now, It works.

see the error message in my anser slways show them in that form, from ! to ?

The error message in full is
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \newfontfamily 
                               
l.4 \newfontfamily
                  \emmentaler{emmentaler-11.otf}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
? 

telling you that \newfontfamily is undefined. That command is defined by teh fontspec package and needs lualatex or xelatex.
so
\documentclass[a4paper,nobib,twoside,symmetric,justified,marginals=raggedouter]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\emmentaler{emmentaler-11.otf}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\begin{document}
\end{document}

lualatex then gives no error (and no output as no text is typeset)

You need to use fontspec and run either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.
Some other notes: you want \newfontface, because the emmentaler-11 font is only available in one shape.
Depending on your application, the chosen amount of scaling might not be the best.
You also need some tweaking so that microtype would not litter the log file with useless warnings (the font misses too many characters and using inheritance with it is moot).
\documentclass[
  a4paper,
  nobib,
  twoside,
  symmetric,
  justified,
  marginals=raggedouter,
]{tufte-book}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text

\newfontface\emmentaler{emmentaler-11.otf}[
  NFSSFamily=emmentaler,
  Scale=MatchLowercase
]

\DeclareCharacterInheritance{<-- keep microtype quiet
  encoding=TU,
  family={emmentaler},
}{}

\begin{document}

Some text {\emmentaler fpsfz}\sidenote{Emmentaler! And let's see what happens
with justification in the side note.}
\lipsum

\end{document}

Since LaTeX keeps informing that
LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s):
    [marginals=raggedouter].

I added a side note to check that the output is as intended.
The package lipsum is just to provide filler text and you don't need it.

